# Multiple Source Folders for Eclipse Java Project & Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

Question/Problem:

How to add an additional source folder to a standard java console Maven project using Eclipse (Luna) so that Maven sees the path for jar build.

The expected result is to somehow configure pom.xml so that Maven plugins in Eclipse can be executed cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions - a successful add of an additional source folder via project (right click) -> new -> source folder.

To let Maven know about the new source folder for building a jar I had to add the following to my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
   <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>[your source folder goes here]/**/*.java</include>
            </includes>
          </configuration>          
     </plugin>                
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.1</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>add-source</id>
           <phase>generate-sources</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>add-source</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
             <sources>
                <source>[your source folder goes here]</source>
             </sources>
           </configuration>
         </execution>
       </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>      
   </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

Be sure to add the **pluginManagement** tags around **plugins** as omitting this tag prevented the mojo plugin to recognize the executions tag.

Perhaps more later on the success of the actual jar construction...

Answer (score 0):

Add generated sources into configuration of maven-compiler-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>[additional directory]</generatedSourcesDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

or provide additional execution:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile-additional-sources</id>
            <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <source>[additional sources]</source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```